# Connecting to FTP sites via squid

Tags: centos, ftp, squid

I'm using the squid proxy on *CentOS* but, I can't connect to FTP sites from WAN. I did open FTP ports in the firewall on CentOS. However, I receive a "Page cannot be displayed" error when I try to connect to FTP sites.

What should I do?

Comment: You need to post more information. Did you configure your browser properly? (Also try a dedicated FTP client.) Did you configure your proxy properly? Do you have a firewall issue? We can't tell, since you didn't give any information about these. And always copy-paste the full error message, not just part of the error (if that's all your browser displays, you may need to click somewhere to get the full error message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below 3 lines to `squid.conf`, and reload squid. Should work for ftp upload and download via squid.

```
acl SSL_ports port 443 21
acl ftp proto FTP
http_access allow ftp
```

[Visit for usefull squid tutorial](http://servercomputing.blogspot.com/search/label/Squid%20Proxy)